# backup linux and windows files to one external fat32 harddrive

Tags: ubuntu, backup, rsync

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to backup files from a linux (Ubuntu, ext4) and Windows (ntfs) partition to an external harddrive (FAT32). I mainly use the linux partition and I tried using rsnapshot but I always get a slew of errors regarding copying of symlinks. I guess this is normal because FAT32 doesn't support symlinks.

Is there another way to back all these files up incrementally like what rsnapshot does while preserving permissions, symlinks, etc?

Comment: Is there a reason the external has to be FAT32? Why not reformat it to NTFS or ext2/3/4? You can use Ext2 IFS or Ext2fsd so Windows can access it, too.

Comment: ntfs won't preserve symlinks.  ext you have to add drivers to windows.  that's why most removable media is ntfs or fat.  ntfs would be a better idea than fat though...it supports a large max file size to the method in my solution could have larger pseudo partitions.

Answer (score 1):

make large files on the fat partition and mount them as a filesystems.  then they can be formatted to look like native filesystems and all your symlinks/etc are preserved

Comment: Sorry, can you expand on this a bit more?

Comment: make a 4GB file of random data(think dd if=/dev/rand of=/pathtofat32/pathtofile bs=whatever count=whatever).  format the file like it's a partition(mkfs.ext3 /pathtofat32/pathtofile). mount it like you would a partition(mount -o loop -t ext3 /pathtofat32/pathtofile /mountpointforthenewfilesystem).  linux doesn't care if it's a file or a device.  all devices are treated like files anyway

Comment: This is a good option. Your desire to back up onto a broken file system like FAT32 is going to end in tears otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Since `FAT32` doesn't support symlinks, permissions, `ACL`s and other advanced file features of `ext4` and `NTFS`, *you can't just copy system files* from a Linux or Windows system partition to a `FAT32` partition.

Anyways, **you can create archive packages** using applications that are able to preserve those features, and save those packages to your *FAT32* partition.

For example, on Ubuntu Linux you can use `tar` to create a backup, in a way similar to the following (I guess one can do something similar also on Windows):

```
# tar czvf /path/to/fat32/backup.tar.gz /
```

Still, you may run in problems, since **`FAT32` file systems can't save files bigger than 4 GB**, and often happen that a system backup needs to be bigger than that.

As a workaround for this problem, you can use a command similar to this to *split* the archive in chunks that can be saved on your FAT32 partition ([see here for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61774/create-a-tar-archive-split-into-blocks-of-a-maximum-size)):

```
# tar czvf - / | split --bytes=4000MB - backup.tar.gz.
```

Exists other tools, like [`dar`](http://dar.linux.free.fr/), that let you create backup archives and natively support automatically split on 4GB.

The 4GB limitation is really annoying, but if you use a system modern enough **can be avoided formatting the partition in `exFAT` instead**. `exFAT` is like `FAT32`, **but can save files bigger than 4GB**, and any system newer than Windows Vista or Mac OS X 10.6 can read and write on it.

To use it with Ubuntu, you just need to install the packages `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse` that should be in universe repository.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux backup please refer to @gerlos 's answer. `tar` is the best practice for backing up ext filesystem.
For Windows, it's best to reboot to another installed Windows, or a Windows PE. Currently the most preferrable method to back up a NTFS volume is to use WIM. Windows has a built-in tool, the [Deployment Image Servicing and Management Tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825236.aspx) `Dism.exe` that can handle wim. Remember **You can never back up a running Windows on itself**. In the alternative Windows system (or Windows PE), run this command (case-insensitive)

```
Dism.exe /Capture-Image /CaptureDir:D: /Name:First /ImageFile:E:\capture.wim
Dism.exe /Split-Image /ImageFile:E:\capture.wim /SWMFile:F:\split.wim /FileSize:4000
```

Note that D: is the volume you want to back up, E: is a temporary place, which **must support files over 4GB**, and F: is the FAT32 volume.
If you are backing it up to a exFAT or NTFS place (recommended), then you don't need to split the image.
To get your backup back, go to an alternative system again and run

```
Dism.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:F:split.swm /SWMFile:F:\split*.swm /ApplyDir:D:
```